# Count number requests of Heroku-Streamlit web app

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit

I deployed a Streamlit application on **Heroku**, which simply displays a web page with a discount code.

The latter is currently embedded in an email - using a link - sent to clients;

I would like to keep track of the number of clicks on that link (aka number of application requests).

I went through documentation (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/metrics) but "number of requests" does not seem to be supported.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest a way to make your own metric for this. You can follow a procedure like below:

1. Attach a Postgresql DB to your Application
2. Create a table called `metrics`

   - With fields: `mertic_id`, `metric_name`, `metric_value`.
   - You can use this to store all the values you need to measure in your app in the future as well.
3. In the `metrics` table create a new row as "app_requests". This metric will count the number of app requests that your app receives.
4. Then inside your source code, you need to add a Database query that will trigger when the app starts. In this case, it should be where the discount page serves. Below are the SQL queries you may need:

   ```
      # Get Current Count
      SELECT metric_value FROM metrics WHERE metric_name="app_requests";
      # Update Count
      UPDATE metrics SET metric_value = 33 WHERE metric_name = "app_requests";
   ```